Interact with multiple cards within NFC range - feasibility
I have a case where I need to interact with 2 EMV cards 'at the same time'. E.g. I need to get some data from both of them, and then make some interactions, first with the card A, and then card B, but both cards are close to the reader.
I have read that EMV cards follow ISO 14443(-3/4) standards, is that correct?
If so, there is something called anti-collision cmd. If I understand it correctly I would be able to utilize it to achieve sequential interactions on 2 cards that are placed close to NFC reader, yes?
Also, about the 'reader', can this be achieved on Android with Android NFC API? It does not support interactions with multiple NFC tags as far as I have tested, but with EMV cards where you send cmds and awaits response APDUs that should not be a problem, right?
I have tested NFC tags interactions on Android NFC API. I have also tried to implement communication according to ISO 14443-4 and do REQA command with old debit cards (MC, Visa), but when I do it I get response 6700 or 6F00. I don't know also what response should I get, but from what I know 6700 or 6F00 can indicate some error rather than correct response. Anticollision command does not work at all.

Not feasible, you don't have low enough level control in Android to do anything like this, you would need full control of the ISO 14443-3 process.
